# C - Read and write bytes from memory

Tags: c, function, memory

I want to have a function that can read bytes from memory and another to write like so:

```
void write_memory(uint32 segment, uint32 offset, char ch);
write_memory(0x750F, 0x00AE, 16);
int read_memory(uint32 segment, uint32 offset);
printf("%d", read_memory(0x750F, 0x00AE));
```

There's probably a function for this already but even if there is I'd be more interested in writing it myself to see how it's done, so how would I write this function.
Thanks.

Comment: Apart from suspending both sanity and portability, this sounds like a *task*; not a question. There is no *question* in your post.

Comment: You don't need any function, just initialize a pointer appropriately. BTW, why the segments thing? Are you on 16 bit x86?

Comment: What attempts have you made so far, what have you tried? What errors have you encountered?

Comment: "how would I write this function". The point is we are here to help *you* write it. If you don't tell us what it is that prevents you from writing those (fairly simple) functions then we can't really help you. What is it *specifically* that you don't understand that is blocking you?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I'm basically trying to write pixels to the screen using mode `13h` I'm writing an OS so I'd do something like this `write_memory(0xA000, (y * SCREEN_WIDTH) + x, color);`

Comment: @kaylum I have tried anything because I just don't know how to do it and if it's fairly simple could you explain

Comment: `*(char*)(segment+offset)=ch;`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @kalyum So would I do `*(char*)(0x760F + 0x00AE) = 16` If i wanted that part of the memory to be 16?

Comment: In pure C yes. But it is not clear whether `0x750F` is accessible in your system as a normal virtual address (assuming your system uses virtual addressing). That's why your question is somewhat unclear - are you asking a pure C question or do you also need to know how to make the address accessible in your program?

Comment: @kaylum I'm my case that address is accessible so it's a pure C question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not "pure C" question, because C language standard doesn't define how to access physical, linear or virtual memory at given address. In many or most environments, operating system won't never let you directly access physical memory, or will only let you access physical memory if you ask it.

For example on Linux with framebuffer, to access framebuffer memory, you have to `open` framebuffer device in write mode, `mmap` it to process memory and write to memory starting at address where it was mapped.

In real mode or v86 mode DOS you can directly access video memory, using FAR pointer. In protected mode with DPMI, the DPMI provides means to access physical memory.

Below are examples for Turbo/Borland C++, Microsoft C and DJGPP:

```
#include <dos.h>
...
#if defined(__TURBOC__)     
    *(unsigned char far*)MK_FP(0xa000, i) = c;
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    *(unsigned char far*)(0xa0000000ul + i) = c;
#elif defined(__DJGPP__) // program is running under DPMI
    dosmemput(&c, 1, 0xa0000 + i);
#endif
```

Comment: I'm writing my own operating system so accessing memory wouldn't be an issue would it?

Comment: Managing memory is one of harder tasks when writing operating system. Unless you're writing real mode only with 640kB limit, you'll have to setup all the segment descriptor tables, page tables and all that stuff. If you haven't been to osdev.org, I recommend starting there. http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page

Comment: Yeah thanks I've been reading some of that what I was trying to use video mode 13 and put pixels on the screen. I also have an unrelated issue where I get a gcc error when I try to compile `ertr000001.o:(.rdata+0x0): undefined reference to _pei386_runtime_relocator'` I'm compiling like this `gcc -ffreestanding -m32 -std=c99 src\kernel.c -o obj\kernel.o -nostdlib -lgcc -lmsvcrt` do you know what could be causing this error? nowhere in my code have i referenced `pei386_runtime_locator`.

Comment: I managed to fix it by using `_main` in my kernel.c file rather than `main` although i now get `obj\kernelasm.o:..\..\..\Desktop\o:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to main'`